# Media Query-Apple Ipad & Phone

Tags: html, css

Please advise on how to apply media query(at what size media query should be applied) for landscape size for apple ipad and iphone screen size.Please also advise will this work on every phone and tablet landscape view.

Comment: Check this http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: thanks @shiva..very informative link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following way :

**Step : 1**

Add following meta tag in HEAD tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Step : 2**

Add media query accordingly device type : 
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Here is Ref http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design

Answer (score 0):

iPad in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {Add your styles here}
```

iPad in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { Add your styles here}
```

iPad in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { Add your styles here }
```

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Large screens ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```